# Background image size is not displaying on firefox

Tags: css, background-image

Background image does not display correctly on firefox, but it works fine on other browsers. Please see [the link here](http://secure.gethope.net/test1/search.html)

```css
body {
  background-image: url('http://mycommunitylink.us/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/HCC_LandPage_1920x10803.jpg');
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Please provide the relevant code *here*, not the whole site.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`background-size` works properly,

**but** you content is in `position:absolute;` so it gives no `height` to body, so no `background` to see in fact.

Where every other browser use html to draw the background and also move the background-size, firefox keeps background-size attached to the actual size of body, it is morelike a bug in my opinion.

> https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html (about backgrounds and colors ... )

You can add:

```
html {
    height:100%;
}
body {
    min-height:100%;
}
```

or use html instead for the background.

Answer (score 1):

This property works:

```
background-size: 100%;
```

Comment: Now the page won't be responsive

Comment: Ok so: `background-size: cover;`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `background-size: 100% 100%;` you should use `cover`. This ensures that the image will cover the full page no matter the size (matches height or width depending which is greater). Like so:

```
body {
  background-image: url('http://mycommunitylink.us/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/HCC_LandPage_1920x10803.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

An ever better way to write out the same thing would be:

```
body {
  background: url('http://mycommunitylink.us/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/HCC_LandPage_1920x10803.jpg') center center / cover no-repeat;
}
```

Edit: The real answer is a combination of @GCyrillus answer, and this one. Add `height: 100%` or `height: 100vh` to the body in order to have a full-height image. Then update `background-size: cover` to stretch the image properly while maintaining ratio.

Comment: This worked for some of my firefox ``background-size`` woes, however, I found using ``background-size: contain;`` worked best for my specific issue - but your answer pointed me in the right direction. Thanks!